# VBA (excel) - How do I feed UserForm Textbox to function?

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, userform

I have a sub that works to clear values from a userform textbox but I tried to convert it to a function so I can use it with multiple userforms.

Here's my userForm Code (the command button code)

```
Private Sub pdclear_Click()
    Dim passform As UserForm
    Set passform = NoteEntryForm1

    Dim inputtext As TextBox
    Set inputtext = frmBigInputBox

Call clear(passform, inputtext)
End Sub
```

Here is my function

```
Function clear(passform As UserForm, inputbox As TextBox)
      passform.inputbox.Value = vbNullString
End Function
```

Trying to execute returns "Type missmatch" error.

I set it as a userform and a textbox. What am I doing wrong?

thank you :)

Comment: I don't think that's your problem, but you should never use names that VB uses. IE Userform Userform, or Sheet Sheet. It confuses it sometimes.

Comment: As @DavidGM points out, call your userform something else (not "userForm1", but like "theForm" or such).

Comment: yes I thought about that. Really bad form. However, this still doesn't make this thing work.

Comment: the line highlighted yellow is this one "Set inputtext = frmBigInputBox"

Answer (score 0):

You define the function to have two parameters. Then in the function you concatenate the parameters as if one is a member of the other. That will give an error. To address the input box on the user form, use:

```
Function clear(passform As UserForm, inputbox As TextBox)
    passform.Controls(inputbox.Name).Value = vbNullString
End Function
```

or even more simple:

```
Function clear(inputbox As TextBox)
    inputbox.Value = vbNullString
End Function
```

(I have not been able to test this as I have no test module with forms in Excel.)

Comment: I don't think it matters whats in the function. The type mismatch is happening in the calling procedure. I don't know why or how to get past it.

Comment: one is a member of the other. If I name the controls specifically it works just fine 
 
NoteEntryForm1.frmBigInputBox.Value = vbNullString

Comment: In stead of `Dim passform As UserForm` try `Dim passform As Object` and for the other object-type variables too.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Type Mismatch` is very clear, you're setting into a variable declared as `TextBox` something that, apparently, is *not* a `TextBox`. 
My suggestions:

1. Check the type using the function `TypeName(object)`, and make sure it's actually a `TextBox`:

   ```
   Debug.Print TypeName(frmBigInputbox)
   ```
2. If the TextBox is a child of the `passform`, then tell this to VBA :

   ```
   Set inputtext = passform.frmBigInputBox
   ```

Comment: NoteEntryForm1.frmBigInputBox is certainly a textbox

Comment: however,  Set inputtext = passform.frmBigInputBox triggers same type mismatch error. :(